# SPLoginViewController to remember credentials

Tags: spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

In CocoaLibSpotify, how do I get SPLoginViewController to store credentials, so users later can login automatically via [[SPSession sharedSession] attemptLoginWithStoredCredentials:]?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't.

Instead, implement the `SPSessionDelegate` method `-session:didGenerateLoginCredentials:forUserName:` and store the credentials in `NSUserDefaults` or whatever (the given credentials are already encrypted and safe for storing in cleartext).

Next time your app launches, if you have available credentials skip `SPLoginViewController`entirely and login using `SPSession`'s `attemptLoginWithUserName:existingCredential:rememberCredentials:` method. If this generates a login error, the token has been invalidated and you need to ask the user to login again — invalidation can happen if the user changes their password since the token was generated.

Note that the `rememberCredentials:` parameters and the old `attemptLoginWithStoredCredentials:` way of doing things is now considered deprecated and will be going away soon.

Answer (score 4):

The previous answer is also no longer relevant as the attemptLoginWithUserName:existingCredential:rememberCredentials: method no longer exists (despite it still being referred to in the comments of SPSession.h)

To get setup:

1. Get the latest cocoalibspotify from github and build it in Xcode:
   https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify
2. build and drop into your project:

To login automatically or prompt for user auth if not previously logged in:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableDictionary *storedCredentials = [defaults valueForKey:@"SpotifyUsers"];

if (storedCredentials == nil)
    [self performSelector:@selector(showLogin) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
else
{
    NSString *u = [storedCredentials objectForKey:@"LastUser"] ;
    [[SPSession sharedSession] attemptLoginWithUserName:u existingCredential:[storedCredentials objectForKey:u]];
}
```

Callback method for storing credentials when logged in:

```
-(void)session:(SPSession *)aSession didGenerateLoginCredentials:(NSString *)credential forUserName:(NSString *)userName
{
    NSLog(@"stored credentials");
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableDictionary *storedCredentials = [[defaults valueForKey:@"SpotifyUsers"] mutableCopy];

    if (storedCredentials == nil)
        storedCredentials = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [storedCredentials setValue:credential forKey:userName];
    [storedCredentials setValue:userName forKey:@"LastUser"];
    [defaults setValue:storedCredentials forKey:@"SpotifyUsers"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```