# Save Spotify logged in user session in iPhone

Tags: iphone, session, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I am implementing Spotify in iPhone. After the user is logged in to the Spotify in my application, I want to keep the user as logged in until he click logout button, ie, even after the application terminate and relaunch, I should get the session. How can we implement it. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read this Forum

[Save Spotify Session](https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify/issues/85)

And also read [remember credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474055/sploginviewcontroller-to-remember-credentials)

Enjoy Programming

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got the credential in . But did not understand that how do we get the result of '[[SPSession sharedSession] attemptLoginWithUserName:credential existingCredential:userName];'.

Comment: attempt login works on existingCredential.Spotify generates your session & other login credentials using didGenerateLoginCredentials method. Where you are also asked to store your session & other login credentials in preferences.After that using existingCredential method spotify compares your storage with its. Thus user is able to login with remember me functionality.

Comment: I got the credential and username. Then from next time app launch, I am calling '[[SPSession sharedSession] attemptLoginWithUserName:credential existingCredential:userName];'. How can I get logged in. Also didn't understand remember me functionality. Please help.

Comment: When you login first time are you calling -(void)session:(SPSession *)aSession didGenerateLoginCredentials:(NSString *)credential forUserName:(NSString *)userName
 method?

Comment: Yes. I get call back in the function.

Comment: fine then as I mentioned in first comment spotify generates & stores credentials using this method.

Comment: Ok. But in next launch, Ishould call 'attemptLoginWithUserName: existingCredential:' right? After that how do I know that I logged in. Is there any call back for 'attemptLoginWithUserName: existingCredential:'.

Comment: after attemptLoginWithUserName call the class that you want to be appeared after spotify login. Thus you will find yourself ogin into spotify

Comment: I got the real problem, ie, in my iPhone with iOS 5, it works fine. But in my iOS 6 iPhone, it takes more than 5 minutes to get the response. Do you have any idea.

Comment: SPSession has the delegate methods `sessionDidLoginSuccessfully:` and `session:didFailToLoginWithError:`. Implement those to be notified when login succeeds or not.

Comment: Yes. I am getting those callbacks in my iOS5 device. But in iOS6 device, it takes more than 5 minutes to get the callbacks.